# Insert K elements into a sorted list of N elements in O(klogk+n)

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity

How could we insert k new elements into a sorted list of size n in time O(k log k + n)?

I guess klogk could come by mergesorting the k elements at first and then inserting them into the size n list. But I am missing the (+n) part.

Comment: You first sort the elements, and then you "merge" these.

Comment: Inserting them into the size `n` list *is* the +n part.

Comment: To add detail to the previous comment, adding even a single element to the middle of a list of size `n` requires moving half the list, which is `O(n)` work.

Comment: Thanks everyone! \

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can first *sort* the elements we want to insert, this can be done, by an algorithm like *merge sort* or *heap* sort, in *O(k log k)*.

Next we can make a *merge* of the two lists (or any kind of datastructure, as long as we can iterate over it in ascending order). This merge can be done in *O(k+n)*, since we concurrently can iterate over the two lists, and each time "emit" the smallest of the two and advance the corresponding cursor.

For example for two arrays that are sorted, we can merge these with:

```
public static int[] merge_sorted(int[] a, int[] b) {
    k = a.length;
    n = b.length;
    int[] c = new int[k+n];
    int ai = 0;
    int bi = 0;
    int ci = 0;
    while(ai < k && bi < n) {
        if(a[ai] <= b[bi]) {
            c[ci++] = a[ai++];
        } else {
            c[ci++] = b[bi++];
        }
    }
    while(ai < k) {
        c[ci++] = a[ai++];
    }
    while(bi < n) {
        c[ci++] = b[bi++];
    }
    return c;
}
```

So the time complexity is *O(k log k + k + n)*, but this is equal to *O(k log k + n)*.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!